# Laravel Login to Admin dashboard redirect to 404 page after enable AuthenticateSession middleware

Tags: laravel, session, authentication, admin, laravel-5.7

Im working in simple blog site using laravel which has 2 parts , blog site for users and admin dashboard

It is all works good before but after uncomment below line in Http/Kernal.php

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
```

failed to login and redirect to admin dashboard and it is redirect to 404 page.

I just want to use `AuthenticateSession` middleware because , i want to use 
**logoutOtherDevices** function for website users

```
 Auth::logoutOtherDevices($request->input('new-password'));
```

when i comment out this line `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class`, again it is working normal .

please help me to solve this issue .

I have `users` table used for login users and `admin` table for login admin to dashboard

here is table for admin :

[image: here is table for admin]

here is `config/auth.php` :

```
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],



    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],


        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],



    ],



    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Model\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Model\Admin::class,
        ]
    ],



    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ]
    ],

];
```

here is admin login function :

```
 public function login(Request $request)
    {
      // Validate the form data
      $this->validate($request, [
        'email'   => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
      ]);

      if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password,'status'=>1], $request->remember)) {
        // if successful, then redirect to their intended location
        return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
      }else{
        // if unsuccessful, then redirect back to the login with the form data
         return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
      }

    }
```

Comment: why not delete all session related to a particular user

Comment: deleting session from `sessions` table will not logout user

Comment: if you delete session then other login user will not able to navigate futher because session does not exist

Comment: then it will give 419 session expired error , but user remains logged in when you reload the page

Comment: then handle session expired error and redirect the user to login page

Comment: @bipin , thanks for your grate suggestion , but it is not work like that